# When using Facebook-Test-Java-API to grab test users of my app, why do some users have their name/email missing?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following library: https://github.com/jayway/facebook-test-java-api
to get information about test users in my private Facebook app.  I can retrieve all of the test users of the app, but when i use FacebookTestAccount.getUserDetails(), for only SOME accounts (~20%) the test account's name and/or email are missing.

Is this a problem with the Facebook-Test-Java-API or do I lack some permission to view that data?  When I view the Test Users of the app via Facebook's Developer App Dashboard, I can see the name/email for all test user accounts.

As far as I know, all of these test user accounts are generated the same way via Facebook's test user creation tool.

Comment: Are you sure all the test users have "installed" the app? I'm fairly sure that if the user has not installed the app then this may be why you are not getting the name and email.

Comment: Interesting, for some test users that are missing both name and email, I think it was because they did not install the app.  When I logged in and installed the app, both name and email were retrieved through the API successfully.

Comment: However, some test users have the app installed but the API is unable to retrieve their email.